# How get more data rate : Change the number of bits, the bandwidth or the packet duration

Tags: bandwidth, throughput

I found definition say that, the rate of packet is define by

*R=N/BD [b/Hz/s]*

where N is the number of bits , B is the bandwidth and D is the packet duration.
So suppose that *R'=N/BD*.

If I would like that my data rate of packet is equal to *R''=2R'*, 
which variable can I change to get *R''*? is it  N,B or D.

Comment: Please clarify your question, by cleary indicating when you mean _data rate_ and when _packet rate_. The terms seems to be a bit mingled in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to double the packet rate you could change any of the things it depends on

- Halve the packet size, or
- Double the bit rate, or
- Halve the packet time

Or change two things appropriately, or all three.

Comment: Hi, is not logical to change any parameter without affect the other. If we double the number of bit to 2N but D allow as to sends only N. Similar Half the time we can not send more then N/2?